# Does the "do not back up" attribute work on data in 'Library/Caches'

Tags: ios, filesystems

Apple's [data storage guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) state the following:

> 2) Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored
>   in the /Library/Caches directory.

...and (emphasis mine):

> 4) Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute
>   with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low
>   storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because
>   customers expect it to be available during offline use. **This attribute
>   works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in**,
>   including the Documents directory. **These files will not be purged** and
>   will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because
>   these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible
>   for monitoring and purging these files periodically.

The page that Apple links to with a more [detailed discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) of this topic does not mention anything about the attribute doing anything to prevent cached data from being purged.

So does anyone know if the "do not back up" attribute actually works like "do not backup and do not delete" for items placed in `/Library/Caches`, or if files still need to be stored inside of the application's `Documents` directory to ensure that they are not deleted when the device is running low on space?

Comment: Have you found an answer? My app has a downloadable content that can be recreated, but is expected to be available offline. Currently I store it in “Caches” directory, but it is purged on low space :( Could the “do not back up” attribute really help? Its name is very frustrating.

Comment: I've checked this and it is really working! Files marked with NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey was not deleted from /Library/Caches directory on a low disk space warning. (I've put an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a quick test on iPhone 5 iOS 7.1.1:

I put some files to *“/Library/Caches”* (`NSCachesDirectory`) and mark them with `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute. Then I put some more big files to the same directory in a normal way.

I then made a low disk space warning by taking a long video with the camera app.
After the warning, files marked with *“do not backup”* was not deleted from Cache, but the other files was! So, this attribute is really working and made two different things in spite of its name – excludes from backup and preserves from being purged on low space warning.

Answer (score 0):

To me this is very clear, and the directory structure is the one I would follow first, just as Apple says. If you both want to save the file and not back it up, put it in Documents, preferably in a folder that you mark.

Even if you observe some behavior today using Caches, it may change in the future.

Comment: Ah, but observed behavior is what I _don't_ have.  I'm trying to infer what behavior _should_ be observed based upon the official documentation.  Which appears to state that files marked as 'do not back up' "will not be purged regardless of what directory they are in".  So it's still about as clear as mud to me.

Comment: Right - so its murky, and you do a test, and iOS does not get purged. In iOS7 though, they do. If you want to try and get a definitive answer, post on the internal Apple forums, but I doubt you will get such an answer from anyone at Apple. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Currently researching this same question and also made the assumption that adding that attribute will prevent a file from being purged in a low disk space scenario (You know, because apple's documentation literally says that). I thought I would update this with my findings since it has been a few years since the accepted answer. I have a database that can be recreated and contains no user generated data, so I store it in caches, but contains some data that can affect the proper functioning of the application, so I don't want it to be purged when running out of disk space (currently happening and logged as a bug). I have experimented with adding the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to the file itself and file is still being removed after purge happens. So it does not seem to prevent purge as of iOS 11.3. Not sure what the next move is as I really don't want to move the database for all our users, but that's probably the next step so it will be safe in Documents. Please correct me if someone has a different experience.